# Cancancan: set authorization for all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

Can I set autorization for all application without putting load_and_authorize_resource in each controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. See this [link](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#4-lock-it-down)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  check_authorization
end
```